# Laravel storage ftp disconnect

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, storage, thephpleague

Is there a way to call the `disconnect()` (in flysystem this function is exists, https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/blob/master/src/Adapter/Ftp.php#L189) function on a ftp-adapter (storage library)?

I do something like this:

```
$ftp = Storage::disk('ftp');
$ftp->makeDirectory('test');
$ftp->disconnect(); // this does not work...
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to call the `disconnect()` method you should be able to:

```
$ftp->getDriver()->getAdapter()->disconnect();
```

Hope this helps!